# Connect Production server sql database from my desktop application

Tags: desktop-application

I have one desktop application. I have database in third party server.  
 I want to do some updates in my database whenever i want through my desktop application.  
I am not bale to connect database with my desktop app. Can you please any one suggest me, how can i connect live server database from my desktop?

Comment: Please add more relevant information, e.g. which database is on server?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Matrix. Go through this article, if You have MySql server: MySQL - Connect to your database remotely | Knowledge Center | Rackspace Hosting http://goo.gl/TXz457

Comment: The same idea valid if You have another database. If critical, take care of security issue. :)